# Excel VBA: Searching through a table from inputted row and column data and showing on listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to write a code to extract a data from a table by inputting the row and column data and showing the result on the listbox to select.

So I have a userform and I'm trying to take in data about the country and quantity, the table that I have has a column heading as "Country" and row heading as "Quantity", so depending on the data inputted by the user, different despatch price will be shown on the listbox.

Here is a picture of my Userform
[image]

Here is a picture of my Table
[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'to search and display in listbox when search button is pressed'

Dim Col As Integer
Dim Row As Integer

cmbCountry.Value("Australia") = 1
cmbCountry.Value("Belgium") = 2
cmbCountry.Value("Canada") = 3
cmbCountry.Value("China") = 4
cmbCountry.Value("China (ET)") = 5
cmbCountry.Value("India") = 6
cmbCountry.Value("Mexico") = 7
cmbCountry.Value("Netherland") = 8
cmbCountry.Value("Peru") = 9
cmbCountry.Value("UK") = 10
cmbCountry.Value("USA") = 11

Row = cmbCountry.Value
Col = txtquant.Value

Price = Sheets("Despatch").DesTable(Row, Col)

ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("Data").Cells(Rowm, 1).Value
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheets("Data").Cells(Row, 2).Value


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code, hope it's help

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    ' better using event Activate to dynamically change the data

    ' extract country list from table
    ' so you can add or remove country directly from your tabel
    
    CountryListArray = Sheet1.ListObjects("DetailTabel").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Value
    CountryList.List = CountryListArray
    
End Sub
```

And this code to pick from cell on table based on choosen country and quantity

```
Private Sub CountryList_Click()
    
    ' check if quantity blank or not
    Quantity = QuantityText.Value
    
    If Quantity = "" Then
        MsgBox "You have fill quantity field"
    
    Else
        ' if quantity field has filled
        LabelDespatch.Caption = Sheet1.ListObjects("DetailTabel").DataBodyRange.Cells(CountryList.ListIndex + 1, Quantity + 1)
    End If
```

End Sub

Result
[image]